# I have created a number guessing game from 1 to 10, Here is the Js code but i am unable to get the output

Tags: javascript

I have created a number guessing game from 1 to 10, Here is the Js code but i am unable to get the output.

Here is my code:

```
var enterButton = document.getElementById('enterButton');
var againButton = document.getElementById('againButton');
var output = document.getElementById('outputText');
var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
function checkNumber() {
  var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  if (input == randomNumber) {
    alert.innerHTML = "Your guess is right " + "," + ",it was " + randomNumber;
  } else if (number > randomNumber && input < 10) {
    alert.innerHTML = "Your guess is to high";
  } else if (input < randomNumber && input > 1) {
    alert.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low ";
  } else if (isNaN(input)) {
      alert.innerHTML = "Invalid operator";
  }
  enterButton.addEventListener('click', checkNumber);
  againButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  })
}
```

Here it the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="sylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>
 
<body>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
</body>
<div id="container">
  <p> Guess a number between 1-10</p>
  <p id="outputtext"> Enter the number below </p>
  <input id="userInput">
  <button id="enterButton">Enter</button>
  <button id="aginButton">Try again</button>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: `input = parseInt(input)` will convert your input (which is a string value) to a *number*.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of issues in your code, first in the html code, you got the id of again button wrong, it should be like this:

```
<button id="againButton">Try again</button>
```

Then in the JS code, you should move the two `addEventListener()` methods out of the `checkNumber()` function definition. Most importantly, you set the input variable to be the value of the input html element. The `value` property returns `string`, and then you compare `randomNumber` with a string which will not work as expected.

Also, the `alert.innerHTML` will not work. [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is a global method which will accepts a `string` type as its parameter. Please see the JS code corrected below:

```
var enterButton = document.getElementById('enterButton');
var againButton = document.getElementById('againButton');
var output = document.getElementById('outputText');
var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
function checkNumber() {
  var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput').value);
  if (input === randomNumber) {
    window.alert("Your guess is right it was " + randomNumber)
  } else if (input > randomNumber && input < 10) {
    window.alert("Your guess is to high");
  } else if (input < randomNumber && input > 1) {
    window.alert("Your guess is too low ");
  } else if (isNaN(input)) {
      window.alert("Invalid operator");
  }
}

enterButton.addEventListener('click', checkNumber);
againButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
})
```

You should also put your `script` tag right before the ending `</body>` tag for it to be able to do its tasks on the DOM elements. Take a look here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="sylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p> Guess a number between 1-10</p>
    <p id="outputtext"> Enter the number below </p>
    <input id="userInput">
    <button id="enterButton">Enter</button>
    <button id="againButton">Try again</button>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe your script tag should be added at the end of the html `body` tag if your code lives in the same directory as your html file, I will edit my response to include the updated `html` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your script. Check out this fixed version.

**UPDATE**
I now put the `<script>` element *ahead of* the `<body>` element to demonstrate the necessitiy of the `window.onload=function(){...}`. My whole script is now placed *within* this function as otherwise, the DOM elements the script refers to, would not yet exist.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="sylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <script>
  window.onload=function(){
    const [form1,againButton,output,inp]="container,againButton,outputText,userInput".split(",")
      .map(id=>document.getElementById(id)), setrndm=_=>randomNumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
    var randomNumber;
    setrndm();
    form1.addEventListener('submit', checkNumber);
    againButton.addEventListener('click', setrndm);

    function checkNumber(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault(); inp.select();
      var input = inp.value;
      if (input == randomNumber) {
        console.log("Your guess is right, it was " + randomNumber);
      } else if (input > randomNumber && input < 11) {
        console.log("Your guess is to high");
      } else if (input < randomNumber && input > 0) {
        console.log("Your guess is too low ");
      } else if (isNaN(input)) {
        console.log("Invalid operator");
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="container">
    <p> Guess a number between 1-10</p>
    <p id="outputtext"> Enter the number below </p>
    <input id="userInput">
    <button id="enterButton">Enter</button>
    <button type="button" id="againButton">Try again</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This code is not working in runtime but when i run the code in console it works only there

Comment: Check out what your console says. If you are uncertain about what happens when, put in some additional console.log statements into your script.

Comment: console is working fine not showing any error , it's just when i enter any number and press enter it doesn't work. and doesn't show any massage

Comment: It looks like the script is not even executed. In the snippet above the `<script src="script.js"></script>` doesn't do anything (as the script is taken directly from the SO snippet) but in your server version it would - hopefully - load your actual script. I hope you have spelled the file name correctly. And, for it to work, the `<script>` tag needs to be placed _after_ the body of your HTML page. I changed my snippet accordingly.

Comment: And keep in mind: pressing the enter key will _not_ trigger the click event on the "enter" button! You will have to _click_ the button.

Comment: I made a few more changes to the code and put it atop the `<body>` element. The code itself is now wrapped in the `window.onload=function(){ ... }`.